# Перебор цифр числа

Tags: c, алгоритм

**Вообщем, дано задание:** Дано два числа `N`, `K`, из цифр N необходимо составить такое число чтобы оно удовлетворяло условию `N < K` и было максимальным.
Пример: `4500789 5000000` , где вывод `4987500`.
Как организовать такой перебор? Возможно у вас имеются какие-то альтернативные решения.

---

Пытался смещениями в право в лево, где каждый старший разряд включает смещение младних, при этом в начале приводил число к максимальному значинию. И всё бы нормально только перебор после `4` разряда специфичен и не поддаётся простому смещению вправо в лево.
Заметил такую особенность, что если число начиная с больших порядков меньше все остальные цифры идут от большего к меньшему.

Comment: Вам нужно одно число? просто составляйте самое малое из чисел :)

Comment: @Harry да, условие щас допишу. максимально возможное число.

Comment: Не понял. *"необходимо составить такое число чтобы оно удовлетворяло условию N < K"* N и K - это входные числа.

Comment: А если перевести числа в строки и сравнивать не цифры, а символы? (не, ну можно потом их превращать в цифры, но, по-моему, в этом нет смысла). Тогда не нужно будет париться с десятичными разрядами и т.п. А когда будет уже готов результат, можно преобразовать обратно готовое число (хотя, опять же - а зачем? все-равно это на экран или в файл выводить - а это можно и как строку).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Перебрать цифры числа N , так чтобы это число имело наибольшее значение и при этом удовлетворяло условию. Да оба числа входные.

Comment: @Vladimir Использование массива хорошая затея да вот только это формальность. В данном случае  важен сам алгорим перебора. И как его осуществить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для удобства имеет смысл оперировать с цифрами как с символами, а с числами как со строками.
1. Символами строки (числа) N заполняем массив Digs[] и сортируем по убыванию.
2. Если длина строки (числа) N меньше длины строки (числа) K, то выводим массив Digs[]. Выход.
3. Если длина строки (числа) N больше или равна длины строки (числа) K, то i=0, j=0, цикл по массиву Digs[]:
4. Пока Digs[i] > K[j] переходим к следующему элементу i++,
5. Выводим Digs[i], Удаляем из массива Digs[i], j++, i=0, возвращаемся в п.4.

i - счетчик по элементам массива, j - счетчик по символу строки (числа) K. Не забываем прервать цикл, если j > длины строки (числа) K.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл задачи сводится к генерации всех возможных перестановок цифр числа N в лексикографическом порядке.
Последовательность действий такая:
Преобразуем число N в массив цифр и сортируем по возрастанию. Это будет самое маленькое число , которое возможно получить из цифр числа N.
Сравниваем получившееся число с M. Если оно больше, то нет решения: из цифр числа N невозможно получить число меньшее M. Если число меньше, сравниваем с М следующую перестановку в лексикографическом порядке. И так до тех пор, пока не получим максимально возможную.
Вот код на  Java:`

```
public class Nm {
/**
* Created by EmelyanovKonstantin on 20.01.2019.
*/   
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите натуральное число N от 0 до 2147483647");
    int n = in.nextInt(); // получаем от пользователя число N
    System.out.println("Введите натуральное число M от 0 до 2147483647");
    int m = in.nextInt(); // получаем от пользователя число M
    Dаrray nArray;
    nArray = bubblesort(toarray(n)); // записываем все цифры чила N в массив и сортируем его. Это будет минимальное число, которое возможно плучить из цифр числа N
    int result = toDec(nArray);
    if (toDec(nArray)> m){
        System.out.println("Любая комбинация цифр числа N больше M");
    }else{
         while(toDec(nArray)<m ) { // пока M больше, генерируем перестановки в лексикографическом порядке
             result = toDec(nArray); // запоминаем предыдущую перестановку. Т.к. нам необходима самая большая, но не превышающая М
             nArray = nextStep(nArray); // получаем следующую перестановку
         }
         System.out.println(result); // Вывод результата
    }
}
static Dаrray nextStep(Dаrray dаrray){ // метод возвращает следующую перестановку в лексикографическом порядке
    // на входе данный метод получает массиф цифр
    int i = dаrray.length()-2; // начиная со второй цифрф
    while (dаrray.data[i]>=dаrray.data[i+1]){ //ищем элемент i, справа от которого стоит элемент больший его
        i--;
    }
    Dаrray tmparray = new Dаrray();
    for (int j = i+1; j< dаrray.length(); j++){ // Формируем хвост: это все элементы справа от i. Вследствии алгоритма эти элементы отсортированны в порядке возрастания
        tmparray.add(dаrray.data[j]);
    }
    for (int k = tmparray.length()-1; k>=0;k--){// В хвосте справа на лево ищем наименьший элемент, который больше i-го
        if((dаrray.data[i]< tmparray.data[k])){// меняем их местами
            int tmp = dаrray.data[i];
            dаrray.data[i] = tmparray.data[k];
            tmparray.data[k] = tmp;
           break;
        }
    }
    bubblesort(tmparray); // сортируем хвост по возрастанию
    for (int h = i+1; h< dаrray.length(); h++){ // вставляем хвост в результирующий массив
        dаrray.data[h]= tmparray.data[h-(i+1)];
    }
    return dаrray;
}
static Dаrray toarray(int a){ // метод преобразования десятичного числа в массив цифр
    Dаrray dаrray = new Dаrray();
    while (a/10 > 0){
        dаrray.add(a%10);
        a=a/10;
    }
    dаrray.add(a);
    return dаrray;
}
static int toDec(Dаrray dаrray){ // метод преобразования массива в десятичное число
    int result = dаrray.data[dаrray.length()-1];
    int d = 1;
    for (int k = dаrray.length()-2; k>=0; k--){
        d= d*10;
        result = result + d*dаrray.data[k];
    }
    return  result;
}
static Dаrray bubblesort(Dаrray arr){ // метод возвращает массив отсортированный по возрастанию
    for(int i = 0; i< arr.length()-1; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j< arr.length()-1-i; j++){
            if (arr.data[j] > arr.data[j+1]){
                int tmp = arr.data[j];
                arr.data[j] = arr.data[j+1];
                arr.data[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
        return arr;
}
```

}
`
Здесь я пояснил всё в комментариях. Ядро всего процесса-метод nextStep. Он генерирует следующую перестановку в лексикографическом порядке. Его суть сводится к:
1.нахождению элемента для перестановки
2.выделению хвоста 
3.нахождению в хвосте минимального элемента, большего чем элемент перестановки
4.перестановке найденных елементов
5.сортировке хвоста 
Существуют различные алгоритмы перестановок как рекурсивные так и не рекурсивные. Более подробный разбор, теорию и формулы по данному вопросу можно  найти тут: https://studopedia.ru/19_379483_generatsiya-perestanovok-v-leksikograficheskom-poryadke.html

Comment: Вы серьёзно? Решение с факториальной сложностью?

Comment: @MBo Да, здесь получается n!